# MediaStore playlist on android

Tags: android

I want to create a playlist in android from which I can query and pull different mp3 tunes when I click next. But I'm not sure how and where to add the files and how to go about this, please can someone advise me how to go about this.

I have looked around on the net but cannot find something a little straightforward. I have found code of how to query this, but I'm not sure of where to start to actually create the playlist. 
I really need help with this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your audio files on the SDcard and run the MediaScanner. Using the native Music Player you can then create a sample playlist.

There is a ContentProvider for accessing playlists, you can probably run a projection(Select) query on it to get details: see [MediaStore.Audio.Playlist](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.html). Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694909/given-an-android-music-playlist-name-how-can-one-find-the-songs-in-the-playlist) thread might give you some idea on how to query the ContentProvider.