# Android Using mediaStore

Tags: android

The Android platform have a number of "ready easy use" dialog such as 
ProgressDialog, DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog, these are fire and wait 
boxes, that is, they handle UI, right data and return something.

Is there a similar dialogbox for the mediastorage ?

I want something like "AudioFilePickerDialog" which shows a UI to the user 
where the user pick a audio file and return the path/uri to the audio file.

Do I need to build this dialog box up myself or does it exists somewhere ?

One of the few examples I have found is 
[Given an Android music playlist name, how can one find the songs in the playlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694909/given-an-android-music-playlist-name-how-can-one-find-the-songs-in-the-playlist)

but this handles playlists.

/Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a tutorial for something like a FileChooser [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/). You should be able to make it only show Music-Files (like `.mp3`).

Also, to browser the SDcard of your Android Device, you can use the standard Java [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)-class, like in normal Java.

Comment: Aha, true, the File-class should be able to do the trick, this might be the other solution can not work with my dialog box, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_MEDIA);//REQUEST_MEDIA is some const int to operate with in onActivityResult
```

here you'll be brought a dialog (activity tbh) to choose an audio from mediastore.
Handle the result in `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_MEDIA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String audioID = data.getDataString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to select multiple music files?

Comment: Standard gallery in 4.0 doesn't support multiple files selection.