# How to query for songs in playlists on Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, playlist, mediastore

So my question is how to query for playlist content. I can make a query to display all the playlists, but how to make a query to display songs in a specific playlist.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694909/given-an-android-music-playlist-name-how-can-one-find-the-songs-in-the-playlist

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, so I have manged to put the code together myself. So this is it :

```
 String[] proj = {   MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE,
                     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID
                    };

            c = getContentResolver().query(   MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",playlistID),
                    proj,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
            startManagingCursor(c);
```