# How to get song title? Android

Tags: android, mediastore

I have song on SD card and I'm trying to get title of that song:

```
File f = new File(filename);

String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, 
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};

Cursor musiccursor = managedQuery(Uri.fromFile(f), 
                        projection, null, null, null);
musicTV.setText(musiccursor.getString(3));
```

but in last line i've got `NullPointerException`.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: read cursor documentation, to begin with

Comment: where is `musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)`? You've assumed that index should have value 3. This is bad assumption and event if it would be good assumption then in java index starts from 0 not from 1.

Comment: Personally, I used null in my projection (so I get all columns) until I figured out how to do it. Then I reduced my query content.

Comment: Hey can you share the answer if possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a cursor, when you are getting some content you have to move the cursor to the first element, because the cursor is pointing before the first element.
Try using:

```
Cursor musiccursor = managedQuery(Uri.fromFile(f),  projection, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
musicTV.setText(musiccursor.getString(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7768631/507120) which gets you 90% there, then [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) will get you the rest of the way.

1. Query Device
2. Init Cursor
3. Traverse Cursor

The hard part is understanding the abstract nature of columns. Just remember it's a database table and can be visualized as a spreadsheet. DON'T FORGET CATCH STATEMENTS!