# Android: Error retrieving songs from a playlist

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm having trouble retrieving songs from playlists in Android. I am currently attempting to achieve this using the following code (based on an answer to this question given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768631/how-to-query-for-songs-in-playlists-on-android-sdk)):

```
String where = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID                   
                  + "=?";

String whereVal[] = {id};

String[] proj = 
{   
     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST,
     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE,
     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID 
};

Cursor mCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", Long.parseLong(id)), 
                proj, where, whereVal, null);
```

where id is the playlist ID that I retrieve using `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));` (and I know that this is correct)

However this is causing the following error:

```
07-06 19:35:02.496: E/AndroidRuntime(8818): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT audio_id, artist, title, 
audio_playlists_map._id AS _id FROM audio_playlists_map, audio WHERE (audio._id = 
audio_id AND playlist_id=?) AND (_id=?)
```

I have a funny feeling that the problem lies in the following: 
`String where = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID + "=?";` but I have no clue how to rectify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the where clause since you already use the content URI of the playlist. I would try this:

```
Cursor mCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", Long.parseLong(id)), 
            proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Yeah you were completely right, I have no idea why I was including the where. Thanks.